# Converting Rose (Board, Int) to Rose Int through Functor instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

-- Rose Int with two children
t1 = MkRose 3 [MkRose 9 [], MkRose 2 []]

data Field = X | O | B
    deriving (Eq, Ord)

type Row   = (Field, Field, Field)
type Board = (Row, Row, Row)

minimax :: Player -> Rose Board -> Rose Int 
-- MkRose -1 [MkRose 1 [..], MkRose -1 [..], MkRose 1 [..] ]
minimax P1 (MkRose b bs)
  = let bs' = minimax' (MkRose b bs) 
-- :t bs' = MkRose (Board, Int) 
--            [MkRose (Board,Int) [], MkRose (Board,Int) [] ]
    in  fmap snd bs'
```

If I have a `Rose (Board, Int)`, I want to be able to convert it to just a `Rose Int`. I switched from attempting a `Functor` instance to just using `fmap` and `snd` on a list, as updated above, which gave me this error:

```
error:
    • No instance for (Functor Rose) arising from a use of ‘fmap’
    • In the expression: fmap snd bs'
      In the expression: let bs' = minimax' (MkRose b bs) in fmap snd bs'
      In an equation for ‘minimax’:
          minimax P1 (MkRose b bs)
            = let bs' = minimax' (MkRose b bs) in fmap snd bs'
    |
259 |     in  fmap snd bs'
```

How can I accomplish this in Haskell? Alternatively I can just write a function, if that's easier.

Comment: You don’t create a functor instance for every monomorphic form of `fmap`. You give a single instance of `Functor Rose`, with a function `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b`, and then use `fmap` at the specific type `((Board, Int) -> Int) -> Rose (Board, Int) -> Rose Int`. (This sort of “adding specificity” is automatic in Haskell; you don’t need to do anything for it to happen.) Also note that `snd :: (a, b) -> b`, so `fmap snd :: Functor f => f (a, b) -> f b` has the type you want (or a superset of that type). Additionally, I recommend reading about the value/type distinction.

Comment: "If I have a Rose (Board, Int)" can you show us a piece of data that you have, an example, like `tree = .....` ?

Comment: Also, I just realized: the program fragment and error that you give don’t match each other. The error says that you wrote the pattern `fmap f (MkRose x xs)`, which doesn’t appear in your fragment. Could you give a complete program that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I've updated my post. The most important here is that I can convert my Rose type, not it being a Functor instance. I will add an example structure for you, @WillNess

Comment: @jlwoodwa Very specifically, where do I need to add the fmap, how does that code need to look, and how will I call it on the list that's on my updated post?

Comment: Easiest path is to let the GHC compiler derive the Functor instance for you. See paragraph 6.6.4.1 in the [compiler documentation](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `fmap`:

```
rmap :: (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
rmap f (MkRose a as) = MkRose (f a) (map (rmap f) as)
```

But having

```
instance Functor Rose where fmap = rmap
```

allows you to do neat things like `(<$)`, and you don't have to keep remembering `map`, `rmap`, `vmap`, etc.

(Also, with `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}`, you can simply write `data Rose a = MkRose a [a] deriving Functor`, and the instance is calculated for you.)

Comment: you are _reimplementing_ `fmap`, so apparently you do need it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add `Functor` to the `deriving` list:

```
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

You might have to enable an extension `DeriveFunctor`.

Then you can just use `fmap snd`.

It will convert `Rose (a,b)` to `Rose b` for any types `a` and `b`. In particular, for `(Board, Int)` it will convert `Rose (Board, Int)` to `Rose Int`, by simply stripping away the first component of the tuple in each value position in the tree.

```
fmap     :: Functor f =>            (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap snd :: Functor f =>                   f (a, b) -> f b
fmap @ Rose ::                   (a -> b) -> Rose a -> Rose b
fmap @ Rose @ (Board, Int) snd :: Rose (Board, Int) -> Rose Int
```

This uses `TypeApplications` but you don't need that, the types will be automatically selected according to the data you will supply, i.e. the variable you will apply `fmap snd` to. For example:

```
Prelude> t1 = MkRose (0,3) [MkRose (0,9) []]
Prelude> fmap snd t1
MkRose 3 [MkRose 9 []]
Prelude>
```

---

What you wrote in the comment is invalid syntax

```
bs' = MkRose (Board, Int) 
          [MkRose (Board,Int) [], MkRose (Board,Int) [] ]
```

if you have this as code, verbatim.

You can't do that. `Board` is a name of a type. `Int` is a name of a type. But a variable `bs'` is supposed to refer to a piece of *data*. If that datum is of type `Rose (Bord, Int)`, it means that in each place where the type variable `a` appears, in the data type definition,

```
data Rose a = MkRose a [Rose a]
--                   ^       ^
```

there supposed to appear *a piece of data of type `(Board, Int)`* -- not simply type *names*. And that is a tuple holding two actual values, one of type `Board`, the other of type `Int`. For example, with `Rose (String, Int)`:

```
t2 :: Rose (String, Int)
t2 = MkRose ("a", 1) [MkRose ("b", 2) [], MkRose ("c", 3) []]

fmap snd t2 
=> MkRose 1 [MkRose 2 [], MkRose 3 []]
```